# Finding the 3D-model of a function that is rotated around the x-axis

Tags: functions, trigonometry, code-request, code

How can I find the 3D model that is created by revolving the function:

```
(5 E^(-(2/
   5) (6000 + t)) (6 Sqrt[11]
     E^2376 (-1 + E^24) Cos[(6 Sqrt[11] t)/
     5] + (-2 + E^2376 + E^2400) Sin[(6 Sqrt[11] t)/5]))/(3 Sqrt[11])
```

Around the x-axis from $t=0$ untill $t=7$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`RevolutionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html) with option [`RevolutionAxis -> "X"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionAxis.html):

```
RevolutionPlot3D[(5 E^(-(2/5) (6000 + t)) (6 Sqrt[11] E^2376 (-1 + E^24) 
   Cos[(6 Sqrt[11] t)/5] + (-2 + E^2376 + E^2400) Sin[(6 Sqrt[11] t)/5]))/(3 Sqrt[11]), 
 {t, 0, 7}, RevolutionAxis -> "X"]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

In version 12, we get this

[image]

with the warning message

> General::munfl: Exp[-2400.] *is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.*